# Postgres user password - Same password work and doesn't work in different places

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, passwords, sudo

`su postgres` - password works.

`psql`, `createuser`, `sudo -u postgres username` - same password doesn't work.

**Error:** `psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

I can log in to postgres user, but anything to do with psql and same password doesn't work. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two completely unrelated passwords here:

- the password to the unix user `postgres` in the operating system; and
- the password to the database user `postgres` in PostgresQL

`su - postgres` requires the password to the *system* user named `postgres`. (By the way, it's better to use `sudo -u postgres -i`). This password is set with the operating system `passwd` command.

Commands like `createdb`, `psql`, etc require the password for the *database user* you're connecting to (if using `md5` password authentication for PostgreSQL). If you're running under the unix user `postgres` or you specify `-U postgres` that is the password for the `postgres` user. This password is set with the `ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'new_password'` command inside PostgreSQL.

Comment: Hmm, interesting! Also thanks for contributing. The problem I seem to have is that I can't even create the user in the first place. I was following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-12-04 and in when attempting to `createuser` I am prompted with password that fails. Is this also the system password?

Comment: `createuser` is a PostgreSQL client that connects with `libpq`, so yes, it's the password for the PostgreSQL user `postgres`. By default this user has no password set, but then, by default it'd use `peer` not `md5` authentication on most installs, including Ubuntu's. So you should't be getting a password prompt if you're running as the `postgres` user (`sudo -u postgres createuser`) unless you changed `pg_hba.conf` to use `md5` authentication.

Comment: I suggest reading https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html then http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html

Comment: Yeah, seems the problem arose from `pg_hba.conf` which a tutorial told me to modify. I simply created a new server from the snapshot and just didn't touch the conf until later time, and it's working now. Also really helpful articles you provided. Thanks so much!